# Push view controller from appdelegate when using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, push

Iam using SWRevealViewController i have a menu 
each element in the menu launch a view controller (TableViewController) when its clicked

I want to show a view when receiving a remote push notification

Case when the application is closed : the code below work correctly

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

// var initialViewController storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
let pushViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsDetailViewController1") as! UINavigationController

let newsViewController = pushViewController.viewControllers[0] as? NewsDetailViewController

self.window?.rootViewController = pushViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

but when the application is opened or in background i can't launch the view controller

the code used in this case :

```
let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController

let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let setViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsDetailViewController1") as! UIViewController
        rootViewController?.navigationController?.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(setViewController, animated: true)
```

i used also this

```
rootViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(setViewController, animated: true)
```

but without result

thanks in adavance for your help